# How to set keep touch on Mac touchpad?

Tags: macos, mac, ipod-touch, trackpad, multi-touch

I am rookie in Mac and I came from Ubuntu

On my previous Dell laptop if I needed to mark some part of text in order to copy or delete it I just made one short touch on touchpad and immediately second touch (not click) and second touch I keep my finger on touchpad and than I can just move mouse and mark text.

or for example how I deleted files:

I have a file on desktop I need to trash it. I put mouse on the file make one short touch and immediately second touch and keep touch on file and now I am able to move file to trash on somewhere on the desktop.

But with mac touchpad I need make click (not just touch) and keep click with one finger and another finger I can move the file somewhere I need. Just remember how you move you file on the desktop, you use two fingers for this.

I hope I describe my problem clearly but feel free to ask

Question is : if there is some settings how to change behavior of touch click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit hidden, but it is possible:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click on Accessibility
3. Scroll down a bit and click on Mouse & Trackpad
4. Click on Trackpad Options…
5. Enable dragging
6. Select "three finger drag"

   [image: Screenshot of System Preferences]

Comment: System Preferences > TrackPad > More Gestures... Select 'with Four fingers'  at Swipe between Full Screen Apps and use four fingers to swipe between windows instead of three fingers